# PHP PDO equivalent to mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using this PDO Query to select from a database:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("select * from tickets where ticketnumber = :seq ");
$stmt->execute(array(':seq' => $_GET["seq"]));
$ticket = $stmt->fetch();
```

but i cannot get an equivalent to `mysql_num_rows`

I have tried doing:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("select COUNT(*), * from tickets where ticketnumber = :seq ");
$stmt->execute(array(':seq' => $_GET["seq"]));
$ticket = $stmt->fetch();
$num_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $num_rows;
```

Comment: @sjagr better not to post this one. it's outdated and all answers there are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Did you bother looking at the manual?

https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows

> Warning
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
> mysqli_stmt_num_rows()
> PDOStatement::rowCount()

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

See: **Example #2 Counting rows returned by a SELECT statement**

With your code it would be:

```
select COUNT(*) from tickets where ticketnumber = :seq
```

You can't select a count and * at the same time. The example shows you to select the count, THEN try to select your rows.

Comment: As far as I know, this particular user positively refused doing any manual or google lookups.

Comment: Not sure why this or the other answer got downvoted, maybe the OP is pissy?

Comment: @Jessica: Probably because you suggested they read through pages and pages of a manual, rather than just write the code for them.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'll need to do 2 separate querys to get the row count as you can't do a `COUNT()` and `*` in the same query.

So you would get the row count using:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("select * from tickets where ticketnumber = :seq ");
$stmt->execute(array(':seq' => $_GET["seq"]));
$ticket = $stmt->fetch();

echo 'Rows: '.$stmt -> rowCount();
```

More information can be found in the manual: [PDOStatement::rowCount](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: Why the down vote? It's the correct answer.

Comment: This does work when the database PDO is connecting to is MySQL. It will give you the actual number of rows in the result. Although the PHP manual says it won't work for most databases other than MySQL. And even in MySQL, it does *not* function like the MySQL `FOUND_ROWS()` function, which allows you to find out how many rows you would have gotten if you hadn't used a `LIMIT` clause. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows